# Difference between href and data-href in anchor tag in html

Tags: html, custom-data-attribute

What is the difference between href and data-href attribute in html `<a></a>` tag?
My current code is written below:

```
<a id="sign_in_with_facebook" href="verify_phone_process_1.html" class="btn btn-default bubbla-btn">Sign In with Facebook</a>
```

and when I'm changing it to

```
<a id="sign_in_with_facebook" data-href="verify_phone_process_1.html" class="btn btn-default bubbla-btn">Sign In with Facebook</a>
```

it's not redirecting to verify_phone_process_1.html page.

Answer (score 13):

> What is the difference between href and data-href attribute in html tag?

That the former actually links somewhere, with all the functionality/UI that includes (because it is *specified* as the attribute that accomplishes that) – whereas the latter does nothing on its own, it’s just an arbitrarily named custom data attribute with an arbitrary value.

---

*Edit:* Some more information on custom data attributes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#custom-data-attribute

Comment: Can you please suggest me any link where I can check about these html5 data attributes?

Comment: I edited the answer to include some links, please have a look.

Answer (score 13):

Global HTML **data-*** attributes are used to store custom data in the HTML code, ready to be called by CSS (`content` used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements) and Javascript.
The asterisk ( * ) is a wildcard that can be substituted by any subtitle.

*In the next snippet the CSS uses data stored in `data-append` to append text `:after` a div's content while Javascript uses the data stored in `data-color` attribute to apply color on its background:*

```js
var div_one = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0]
var div_two = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1];

div_one.style.background = div_one.getAttribute("data-color");
div_two.style.background = div_two.getAttribute("data-color");
```

```css
div::after {
  content: attr(data-append);
}
```

```html
<div data-append="_SUCCESS_" data-color="lawngreen"></div>
<div data-append="_FAILURE_" data-color="tomato"></div>
```