# How to open new tab using data-href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a table row clickable but once clicked I want to open a new tab. I tried using `data-target` but that didn't work.

```
<tr class="table-row" data-href="mypage.php" data-target="_blank"></tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".table-row").click(function () {
            window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: have a look at this post and check out the accepted answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245279/wrapping-html-table-rows-in-a-tags Is that something you'd be able to implement?

Comment: Any chance to add a link like `<a href="your-url.php" target="_blank">hello world</a>` inside the `<tr>`

Comment: Have you tried just `target="_blank"`?

Comment: @Edward, I tried that but no luck

Comment: @caramba, that doesn't work either

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36020130/difference-between-href-and-data-href-in-anchor-tag-in-html

Comment: @Jonathan works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/mc7sef5s/

Comment: @caramba, cool. What do you do though when you have more than one <td> in the <tr>?

Comment: @Jonathan then you add the link inside every `<td>` or you do something with javascript it depends on a few things and there is a ton of responses for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1461009/2008111 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/4904983/2008111 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/17147973/2008111 after your update also have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5141926/2008111

Answer (score 5, accepted):

could be done like this:

**jQuery: [JSFiddle 1](https://jsfiddle.net/wxc80ybf/2/)**

```js
$('.table-row').each(function() {
  var $th = $(this);
  $th.on('click', function() {
    window.open($th.attr('data-href'), $th.attr('data-target'));
  });
});
```

---

**Pure JS: [JSFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/wxc80ybf/3/)**

```js
var tableRows = document.getElementsByClassName('table-row');

for (var i = 0, ln = tableRows.length; i < ln; i++) {
  tableRows[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    window.open(this.getAttribute('data-href'), this.getAttribute('data-target'));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work. It will open new tab;

HTML

```
  <table>
        <tr class="table-row" data-href="mypage.php" data-target="_blank">
          <td>something</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".table-row").click(function () {
        window.open($(this).data("href"), $(this).data("target")); // Open new tab line
    });
});
```

Comment: I still don't see that having to specify a url twice is a good way to go?

Comment: repalced url with window.location.href. But i see it works fine without it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<tr class="table-row" 
onclick="window.open('http://website-name.com/mypage.php', '_blank');">
```

Comment: This opens a new tab as I want but the initial page then redirects to mysite.com/undefined

Comment: add this: window.open('http://wbsite-name.com/mypage.php', '_blank'); after window.document.location = $(this).data("href"); - it should redirect and then open empty tab.

Comment: But then I am specifying a url twice as I already have the url in the data-href?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use `windows.open` and you can use `_blank`

```
<tr class="table-row" data-href="mypage.php">


$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(".table-row").click(function () {
    var url = $(this).data("href");
    window.open(url,'_blank');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. If I do that and click on the link it takes me to mysite.com/undefined

Comment: Sorry, I see it was doing that because I had some javascript. I removed that javascript and now nothing happens at all when I click on the link. I will post the jQuery in my original question.