# Add a link to a table row that opens URL to a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've already tried a number of threads but so far I can't get it to work.

I got the rows clickable to a new URL but it opens in the same tab, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147973/12008992) worked.
However, I want the URL to open in a new tab. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855603/12008992) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855469/12008992) but no luck.

I even tried to modify the first option from `window.location` to `window.open` but it is not responding.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".click-row").click(function() {
        window.open($(this).data("href"));
    });
});
```

```
    <table> 
       <tbody>
          <tr class='click-row' data-href="/Documents/files/file.pdf"> 
             <td>Link to file</td> 
          </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: Try this instead: `window.open($(this).data("href"), "_blank");`

Comment: Try this ``window.open($(this).data("href"), '_blank');``

Comment: Actually your code is working fine to me

Comment: @annoyingmouse I thought I already tried this a hundred times but apparently not. This works great! Thanks a lot to all of you!

Comment: @BadPiggie i couldnt really find a mistake in the code that i used. No idea why it is not working for me... But thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

Always use target="_blank" for open URL in New Tab

```html
<table> 
       <tbody>
          <tr class='click-row' data-href="/Documents/files/file.pdf" target="_blank"> 
             <td>Link to file</td> 
          </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table>
```

Comment: That is for anchor tags `<a>` solely, it won't affect OP's jquery code in any way. Don't know why this received an upvote